# Show first and last label in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, legend

I have a DataFrame with 361 columns. I want to plot it but showing only the first and last columns in the legend. For instance:

```
d = {'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4],'col3':[5,6],'col4':[7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I plot through `df.plot()` all the legends will be displayed, but I only want `'col1'` and `'col4'` in my legend with the proper color code (I am using a colormap) and legend title.

One way to do this is to plot each column separately through matplotlib without using legends and then plot two more empty plots with only the labels (example below), but I wonder if there is a direct way to do it with pandas.

```
for columns in df:
    plt.plot(df[columns])
plt.plot([],[],label=df.columns[0])
plt.plot([],[],label=df.columns[-1])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try extracting the handlers/labels from the axis and defining new legend:

```
ax = df.plot()
handlers, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
new_handlers, new_labels = [], []

for h,l in zip(handlers, labels):
    if l in ['col1','col4']:
        new_handlers.append(h)
        new_labels.append(l)
        
ax.legend(new_handlers, new_labels)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Well, it does work but I am asking for a more direct way, i.e. without loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split your df into two dfs which the second one will contain only the columns of interest and then plot both dfs showing only the second legend.